# showing an element is in a normal subgroup whose order and the order of the factor group is relatively prime

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let H be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and let $x \in G$. If $\gcd\left ( \left | x \right |,\left | G/H \right | \right )=1$, 
>   show that $x \in H$.

Attempt:

Let $H \triangleleft G$.
So, $\forall x \in G: xH =Hx 
\Rightarrow xHx\subseteq H$

Since H is a normal subgroup of G: $\left | G:H \right |=\frac{\left | G \right |}{\left | H \right |}=\left | \frac{G}{H} \right |=2$.

I would appreciate hints to keep me going.

Comment: Why is $|G/H|=2$ again?

Comment: Because the index of a normal subgroup is 2.

Comment: This is not true. Normal subgroups can be of arbitrary index. For example, in an Abelian group, every subgroup is normal. Are you saying then that every subgroup has index 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Your conclusion that $\because H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, hence $[G:H]=2$ is incorrect (as noted in comments as well). All we can say is that $[G:H]$ is finite (because $|G|$ is finite).

Let $|x|=a$ and $|G/H|=b$. We are given that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore there exists $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ma+nb=1$.

Now consider the coset $xH$. 
$$(xH)^a=x^aH=eH=H \quad \implies \quad x^a \in H.$$
Likewise
$$x^bH=(xH)^b=H \quad \implies \quad x^b \in H.$$
Now
$$x=x^1=x^{ma+nb}=\underbrace{x^{ma}}_{\in H} \, \overbrace{x^{nb}}^{\in H} \in H$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $x\notin H$, then look at the coset $xH$ in the group $G/H$. What does Lagrange's theorem say about the order of $xH$?

Comment: The order of xH divides the order of G/H but the order of xH is just the order of x....

Comment: Well the order of $xH$ doesn't have to be equal to the order of $x$, but it does need to divide it.

Comment: If the order of xH divides the order of x, then the order of x is some multiple of the order of xH

Comment: Yes, now conclude using the gcd assumption.

Comment: The divisor of n |xH| is either n, |xH|, 1 or n|xH|. By assumption, the divisor for both order is 1. Sorry, I can't figure it out.
I could only see that the divisor of  $n_{1}$|xH| is $n_{1}$, |xH|, 1 or $n_{1}$|xH|

Comment: The point is that the order of $xH$ divides $|x|$ and $|G/H|$ so it has to divide their gcd, which is $1$. so $x\in H$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\langle x \rangle$ by $K$. As $H \lhd G$, $KH$ is a subgroup of $G$. By second isomorphism theorem,
$$|KH|= \frac{|K||H|}{|K \cap H|}\, | \, |K||H|,$$
so $|KH|$ is coprime to $|G:H|$, since both $|K|$ and $|H|$ are so.

Suppose $x \notin H$, $|KH| \gt |H|$, so $|KH|$ is a divisor of $|G|$ which is coprime to $[G:H]$ but strictly larger than $|H|$, a contradiction.