# Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $x \in G$. Show that if the greatest common divisor $(| x |, | H |) = 1$ , then $x \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $x \in G$. Show that if  the greatest common divisor $(| x |, | H |) = 1$ , then $x \in H$.

Since $H$ is the normal subgroup of $G$ then we know that $xH = Hx$ for every $x \in G$. Thus, $xh \in Hx$ for all $h \in H$. Then $xh = h_{1}x$ for some $h_{1} \in H$. I want to show that $x \in H$. Is it enough to show that $H = xH = Hx$?

In general I have difficulty in applying the greatest common divisor. I know for $x^{|x|} = 1_{G}$ for some $x \in <x>$ and also $h^{|H|} = 1_{H} = 1_{G}$ for some $h \in H$. How to use the fact that the greatest common divisor is $1$?

Comment: I don't think this is true.... Surely you want $\gcd(|x|,|G|/|H|)=1$?

Comment: If it is not true there must be some counterexample. But for me the question is exactly like that. What would change if it were $|G|/|H|$?

Comment: If you changed it to $|G|/|H|$ you would get a theorem that you could prove, rather than an assertion to which finding counterexamples is trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [showing an element is in a normal subgroup whose order and the order of the factor group is relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353101/showing-an-element-is-in-a-normal-subgroup-whose-order-and-the-order-of-the-fact)

Comment: I understand, the subgroup $<1_{H}> = \lbrace 1_{H} \rbrace$ is normal in $G$ and satisfies the hypothesis of the statement however for any $g \in G$ other than identity if it has $g \notin <1_H>$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given, the statement is false.  Let $G$ be the integers mod $6$, $x$ be $2$, and $H$ be the subgroup $\{0, 3\}$.